# Are "pater", "parens", "parturitio", & "partitio" etymologically related?

Tags: etymology, word-comparison, noun, origin, familia

Are [*pater*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=pater) (father), [*parens*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=parens) (procreator), [*parturitio*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=parturitio) (parturition), and [*partitio*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=parturitio) (partition) etymologically related?

Phonetic and semantic similarities lead me to think they might be related. I can't remember where, or if it's even a non-folk etymology, but I read somewhere that *pater* and *partitio* are related, in the sense that when one opens or "partitions" the womb, one becomes a father.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on possible relations? Did you check the etymology or the derivation history within Latin anywhere? Reducing these words to the most basic underlying Latin words will simplify the task.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Phonetic and semantic similarities. I can't remember where, or if it's even a non-folk etymology, but I read somewhere that _pater_ and _partitio_ are related, in the sense that when one opens or "partitions" the womb, one becomes a father.

Comment: It might be useful to include background like that in the question. I was not the one to vote down; I just suspected the reason someone did it was a lack of presented rationale. I edited your comment into the question, but feel free to edit further or roll back. That connection between *pater* and *partitio* sounds much like folk etymology, given all the other uses of *partitio* and the way it comes from *pars*. I gave an answer which hopefully gives a method to get started with questions like this.

Answer (score 4):

#### Reduction of the problem

It is good to preprocess the data and reduce the words into simpler constituents within Latin.
We can reason as follows:

- *pater*
- *parens < parere*
- *parturitio < parturire < parere*
- *partitio < partire < pars*

This reveals that *parens* and *parturitio* are already well linked within Latin, both coming from *parere*.
Now it remains to compare *pater, parere, pars* or their stems *patr-, par-, part-*.

If you want to assess whether two words look similar, do it at this level.
If there are many layers of derivation and morphology, the similarity could be due to that.
Strip away any prefixes and derivations you can.

#### Derivations

Perhaps it is useful to explain the derivations above.

- *Parens* is (close to) the present participle of *parere*, "to produce offspring".
  (There are many possible translations, but let me stick to this one here.)
  The regular participle would be *pariens*, but losing the *i* is hardly a far fetch, especially given the meanings of the words.
  The participle *pariens* is attested and seems to be used as a participle, but *parens* has taken up a life more independent of the verb.
- *Parturire* is "to desire to produce offspring" or "to be about to produce offspring".
  The meaning "to be pregnant" is hardly a surprise.
  Derivations like this in *-urire* are formed from the perfect participle, which for *parere* is *parit-* or *part-*.
- *Parturitio* is a noun for the action of *parturire* and has also the meaning "to give birth".
- *Partire* means "to share or divide", from *pars*.
- *Partitio* comes from *partire* just like *parturitio* from *parturire*.

#### Etymologies outside Latin

I am by no means an expert on this, so I will simply report what is on Wiktionary.
Others better versed in etymology can probably give details.
(Feel free to edit details in if you find that useful.)

- Wiktionary derives [*pater*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pater#Latin) from PIE **ph₂tḗr*.
- Wiktionary derives [*parere*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pario#Latin) from PIE **perh₃-*.
- Wiktionary derives [*pars*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pars#Latin) from PIE **perH-* or **per-*.

The conclusion is that these three appear to be unrelated.